# how to link the predicted output to the original observation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, data-mining

Am working on a binary classification using logistic regression data

I have 1000 rows and 28 features. Three to 4 variables are Id variables like product_id, subject_id etc

During train_test split, I drop them like as shown below

```
X = df.drop(['status','Product_ID','subject_ID'], axis=1)
y = df.status
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.25,
                                                    random_state=0)
```

Once I do this I do some preprocessing and modelling tasks as below

a) `encoding` categorical variables for train and test separately
b) `model.fit()`
c) `model.predict()`
d) Finally, I get the `y_pred` and I compare it with `y_test`.

My question are as follows

a) when there is no identifier in `y_pred`, how can I link back to get the full row of that instance? Meaning, I want the full data row of that observation along with new column `predicted_status` (beside already existing actual `status` column). Is there anyway to include `ID` variables in model building process but make their effect as 0 (or just stay there as a useless column)

b) Would the same order be preserved during train-test split,encoding,cross-validation,testing etc

c) What happens if we split train and test based on some criteria like year between 2015-2020 (becomes train) and anytime after 2020 becomes test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `subject_ID` and after train_test_split pass to the model dataframes without the ID column, as in:

`df.loc[ : , df.columns != 'subject_ID']`

Unless you are explicitly shuffling datapoints during prediction, I believe that commonly returned predictions persist the initial order. Definitely worth checking with the particular model you are using.

EDIT:

See an example of entire process below:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
# you don't need this, you have subject IDs.
iris['Subject_ID'] = numpy.random.randint(1, 10000, iris.shape[0])
# use subject IDs as index.
iris.set_index('Subject_ID', inplace=True)

# Split your data, index will be persisted.
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(
               iris.loc[ : , iris.columns != 'species'], 
               iris['species'],
               random_state=1
               )

# Model and predict.
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB  # 1. choose model class
model = GaussianNB()                        # 2. instantiate model
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)                   # 3. fit model to data
y_hat = model.predict(Xtest, )              # 4. predict on new data

# Append predictions, original datapoint IDs will be encoded in the index.
Xtest["predictions"] = y_hat

# Test by joining original labels, using a dummy dataset for prediction.
Xtest = Xtest.join(iris['species'], how='inner')
Xtest.head()
>>>
```

| Subject_ID | sepal_length | sepal_width | petal_length | petal_width | predictions | species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2265 | 5.8 | 4.0 | 1.2 | 0.2 | setosa | setosa |
| 1961 | 5.1 | 2.5 | 3.0 | 1.1 | versicolor | versicolor |
| 4177 | 6.6 | 3.0 | 4.4 | 1.4 | versicolor | versicolor |
| 6041 | 5.4 | 3.9 | 1.3 | 0.4 | setosa | setosa |
| 8500 | 7.9 | 3.8 | 6.4 | 2.0 | virginica | virginica |

Comment: thanks, upvoted. BUt after prediction, how do I link back?

Comment: See example, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, one question on this. I know we usually predict on `test set`. But we can also predict on train set and link their prediction back to the train data points. Am I right? While I understand it doesn't make sense to train and predict using the same dataset. But to verify the confusion matrix of train set, I have to predict on train set; Am I right?

Comment: Of course, test set prediction is usually considered for performance of model but is it okay to build confusion matrix, precision recall etc for train set as well?

Comment: In the above code, you have not excluded `subject_id` column from being passed to the model? However, your text says we should remove it from being fed to the model. Sorry, if I understood this incorrectly. can help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure it is not excluded? If you try an `iris.columns` or `iris.Subject_ID` after `set_index('subject_ID', inplace=True)` you will see that it is not part of the dataset anymore. In the very last table, the Subject_ID column is still index of the dataframe.

Comment: On your other question, yes you can predict on train set. Practically, I treat here `test` to mimic your example above. In a real world scenario, test set more commonly sould have been your validation set, as prediction on the test set should be used as a very final evaluation of your model. But you can play around all you want with train and val. If you are not familiar with the above it may be worth looking online or ask another question.

Comment: For a confusion matrix before touching the test set, you should be using a validation set, and perform cross validation - unless you have a very big dataset in which case it is not a requirement (standard practise in deep learning for example)

Comment: So, what we call as usual `train` and `test` is actually `train` and `val` datasets. Am I right? `Test` dataset is totally unseen (brand new)

Comment: By train test split, we just split them into `train` and `val`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133836/discussion-between-hh1sg0n3-and-the-great).